# Where is the Eclipse's preferences stored locally?

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-juno

I have an old Eclipse stored under '**/Applications**', and today I download the latest `Juno` and open in the Desktop, I found the `Juno` is able to read my current config, e.g. code formatter settings, color theme.

Are these settings stored in a globally readable place?

(I am using Mac OSX, and not import/export of preferences were performed.)

Answer (score 6):

Most settings are stored in the workspace in the `.metadata` folder. Specially `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings`

Some are stored in the `configuration` folder in your Eclipse installation folder.

Comment: Yes, this is the funnest thing. I extracted the latest eclipse in my `Downloads` folder and it is still able to read my existing config.

Comment: Did you point it to an existing workspace?

Comment: Yes, found the `.settings` finally. So does it mean when I am using the same workspace, I can switch Eclipse concurrently?

Comment: You _can_ do it, but I don't think it is recommended since they might change how the preferences are handled between different Eclipse versions. The proper way would be to export your preferences from the old workspace and import into a new one.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, why this question get closed as "off topic"? Did the moderator read the FAQ: "..software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: "Most ...", "Some are stored... " -- In other words, the settings are all over the place (well I have seen worse but still).